# Magento 2 : Show custom table data in grid

Tags: magento2.3, adminhtml, grid, custom

I have created a form and the data of that form is saving in a custom table. Now I want to create a grid in admin which shows the saved data in that table. Please help

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

> Vendor\Module\etc\di.xml

```
<virtualType name="Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Module\Grid\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">custom_table_name</argument>
        <argument name="eventPrefix" xsi:type="string">custom_table/argument>
        <argument name="eventObject" xsi:type="string">custom_table</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\\Model\ResourceModel\Module</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

> Vendor\Module\Model\Module.php

```
class Module extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
{

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Module');
    }

    public function getDefaultValues()
    {
        $values = [];

        return $values;
    }
}
```

> Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Module.php

```
class Module extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
{

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('custom_table_name', 'primiary_key');
    }
}
```

> Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Module\Collection.php

```
class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
{
    protected $_idFieldName = 'primary_key';

    /**
     * Define resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Vendor\Module\Model\Module', 'Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Module');
    }
}
```

> Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Module\Grid\Collection.php

```
class Collection extends \FME\ProductSliders\Model\ResourceModel\ProductSliders\Collection implements \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchResultInterface
{
    protected $_aggregations;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        $mainTable,
        $eventPrefix,
        $eventObject,
        $resourceModel,
        $model = 'Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Document',
        $connection = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $connection, $resource);
        $this->_eventPrefix = $eventPrefix;
        $this->_eventObject = $eventObject;
        $this->_init($model, $resourceModel);
        $this->setMainTable($mainTable);
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Search\AggregationInterface
     */
    public function getAggregations()
    {
        return $this->_aggregations;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Search\AggregationInterface $aggregations
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setAggregations($aggregations)
    {
        $this->_aggregations = $aggregations;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve all ids for collection
     * Backward compatibility with EAV collection
     *
     * @param int $limit
     * @param int $offset
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllIds($limit = null, $offset = null)
    {
        return $this->getConnection()->fetchCol($this->_getAllIdsSelect($limit, $offset), $this->_bindParams);
    }

    /**
     * Get search criteria.
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface|null
     */
    public function getSearchCriteria()
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Set search criteria.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria
     * @return $this
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function setSearchCriteria(\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria = null)
    {
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get total count.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getTotalCount()
    {
        return $this->getSize();
    }

    /**
     * Set total count.
     *
     * @param int $totalCount
     * @return $this
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function setTotalCount($totalCount)
    {
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set items list.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensibleDataInterface[] $items
     * @return $this
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function setItems(array $items = null)
    {
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have created html form in frontend and its value is saved in a database table. Now i want to take data from that table and save in admin grid

Comment: check my updated answer hope you got some idea now its upto you whether you create grid using ui_component or Block